# Steering tight and orange fluid on ground after failure to start

Tags: power-steering, steering, leak, infiniti

This morning, my car wouldn't start so a friend of mine and I tried to push start it, with no luck. We got around a corner in my neighborhood and fortunately found someone who could jump it. Afterwards, as soon as I reverse, I notice there is a puddle of orange-ish fluid on the ground and my steering is SUPER tight. I need help figuring out exactly what is going on, because I know I shouldn't be driving it in it's current state.

Comment: What is the Make, Model, Year of the car?

Comment: It's a 1995 Infiniti G20. But it does have a SR20 engine swap in it.

Comment: Some cars (I was hoping you would say Ford) are known to puke up power steering fluid if the steering wheel is turned without the engine running. Refill the power steering fluid with the correct fluid for your car. Bleed the air out by turning the wheel back and forth lock to lock.

Comment: And that should put my steering back to it's original state? Alright, I'll give that a shot and keep you posted through this thread. Thank you very much, @vini_i

Comment: If it was not obvious turn the wheel back and forth with the engine running to bleed the air out. Fill the reservoir to the full mark, no higher. Then start the car and work the wheel back and forth lock to lock, the best you can. Turn the car off and check the fluid. If the level dropped fill it up to the full mark again. Lather rinse and repeat until the level does not drop anymore.

Answer (score 4):

**You need to identify the source of the leak**

Clean everything in your driveway.  Use Gunk, water soluble, or the like and get the Power Steering Fluid gone.  Then:

- Allow everything to dry out.
- Validate any leaks...mind you, you have not started the engine since you cleaned EVERYTHING that could be consider oil out of the engine bay.
- Now, start it and run.  You have talcum powder.  If you can't identify the leak you are throwing talcum powder around.  You are underneath the vehicle looking up.  You have a very bright light, even in the day, and are searching for a leak.
- You will identify it and then ask another question about how to resolve it.

***the first step is identifying what part the liquid is shooting out of***